# How to save combobox data into SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I tried this code, and without combobox it's working.

After adding `combobox(comboBloodGroup)` with 8 selected items and data type selected is `nvchar(50)`, I get an error

How to code to insert combobox data into sql database.

My new code is

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {         
            string strConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\MYPC\DOCUMENTS\LOGIN.MDF";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            cn.Open();
            int iId = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text.Trim());
            string strFName = txtFName.Text.Trim();
            string strLName = txtLName.Text.Trim();
            int iAge = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text.Trim());
            string stremail = txtemail.Text.Trim();
            string strMobile = txtMobile.Text.Trim();
            string strAddress = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
            string strCity = txtCity.Text.Trim();
            int iPinCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtPinCode.Text.Trim());
            string strGender;
            if (rbMale.Checked)
                strGender = "Male";
            else
                strGender = "Female";
            string strBloodGroup = comboBloodGroup.SelectedItem.ToString();                
            DateTime dtDOB = dtPickerDOB.Value;
            string query = "INSERT INTO information(Id, FName, LName, Age, email, Mobile, Address, City, PinCode, Gender, BloodGroup, DOB)VALUES(@iId, @strFName, @strLName, @iAge, @stremail,@strMobile, @strAddress, @strCity, @iPinCode, @strGender, @strBloodGrourp, @dtDOB)";
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            InsertCommand.Connection = cn;
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iId", iId);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strFName", strFName);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strLName", strLName);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iAge", iAge);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stremail", stremail);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strMobile", strMobile);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strAddress", strAddress);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strCity", strCity);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iPinCode", iPinCode);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strGender", strGender);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strBloodGroup", strBloodGroup);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtDOB", dtDOB);
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();             
            MessageBox.Show("New Patient's Data has been added successfully");
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: the error is "must declare the scalar variable '@strBloodGroup'."

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped @strBloodGrourp in query. Change to @strBloodGroup.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO information(Id, FName, LName, Age, email, Mobile, Address, City, PinCode, Gender, BloodGroup, DOB)VALUES(@iId, @strFName, @strLName, @iAge, @stremail,@strMobile, @strAddress, @strCity, @iPinCode, @strGender, **@strBloodGrourp**, @dtDOB)";
```

And you add parameter **@strBloodGroup**

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name you defined in your command and your `AddWithValue` doesn't match. You defined it as `strBloodGrourp` in your command but you declared it `strBloodGroup` in your `AddWithValue`.

Change your parameter name in your command as;

```
@strGender, @strBloodGroup, @dtDOB
```

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- Don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

---

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
using(var InsertCommand = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property with parameter names.
    // Define your parameter names and it's values. Add them to your command.
    // Open your connection.
    // Execute your query.
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

`string query = "INSERT INTO information(Id, FName, LName, Age, email, Mobile, Address, City, PinCode, Gender, BloodGroup, DOB)VALUES(@iId, @strFName, @strLName, @iAge, @stremail,@strMobile, @strAddress, @strCity, @iPinCode, @strGender, @strBloodGrourp, @dtDOB)";`

Should read

`string query = "INSERT INTO information(Id, FName, LName, Age, email, Mobile, Address, City, PinCode, Gender, BloodGroup, DOB)VALUES(@iId, @strFName, @strLName, @iAge, @stremail,@strMobile, @strAddress, @strCity, @iPinCode, @strGender, @strBloodGroup, @dtDOB)";`

You had an extra R in bloodgroup